# How to position a rectangle into upper left corner inside of a frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I am able to draw a rectangle inside a frame using tkinter but when window is maximized, the rectangle is no longer at upper left corner of the frame.

How do I pin the rectangle to the upper left corner of the frame ?

This is what I have:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

f1 = Frame(height=100, bd=2, relief=RAISED)
f1.pack(fill=X, padx=3, pady=3)

c = Canvas(f1)
c.create_rectangle(1,1,100,90)
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pack manager, you can use the place manager.  You would replace the

```
f1.pack(fill=X, padx=3, pady=3)
```

with

```
f1.place(x=0,y=0)
```

See, for instance, [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).  Of course, using absolute positioning can make your layout very sensitive to the particular window dimensions.

Comment: The f1 frame placement is ok, it extends all the way from upper left. It is the triangle that I need placed at upper left.

Comment: Then you can use `place` instead of `pack` for it.

Comment: How ? It does not work. The rectangle is somewher in the middle. There is no rectangle.place().

Comment: Replacing `c.pack()` with `c.place(x=0,y=0)` works with Python 2.7.6.  However you might be better off with the `c.pack(fill=X,padx=3, pady=3)` you showed in your answer or with `c.pack(anchor=NW)`.

Comment: Also, did you even try my original suggestion above?  `f1.place(x=0,y=0)` works fine with Python 2.7.6, as does `f1.pack(anchor=NW)`. The problem is that the fill=X in the frame places the fill around the contained pieces (the canvas), which is unlike what fill=X is doing when applied inside the canvas.

Comment: Also, did you even try my original suggestion above?

Comment: Did you ? Your solution not working correctly on Linux Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Yes, I had tested them.  I just retested them; results the same: code from your question fails; same code with my original `f1.place(x=0,y=0)` suggestion works; question code with `c.place(x=0,y=0)` or `c.pack(anchor=NW)` works, and your answer code works. All with Python 2.7.6 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After a few iterations of the above code, this worked for me:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

f1 = Frame(height=100, bd=2, relief=RAISED)
f1.pack(fill=X, padx=3, pady=3)

c = Canvas(f1)
c.create_rectangle(1,1,100,90)
c.pack(fill=X,padx=3, pady=3)

mainloop()
```